# sed - how match exactly number in line

Tags: linux, sed

Please advice , how to tell sed to match exactly the number

for example ,

regarding the file.csv file we want to change the word **STATUS** to **OK** only on line that start with number 1 (before the "," seperator )

but sed replace the **STATUS** to **OK** also on LINE that start with 12

so how to change my sed syntax to match exactly the first number before the separator?

```
 more file.csv

 1,14556,43634,266,242,def,45,STATUS
 12,4345,1,43,57,24,657,SD,STATUS
 3,1,WQ,435,676,90,3,44f,STATUS


  sed "/^1/ s/STATUS/OK/g" file.csv
  1,14556,43634,266,242,def,45,OK
  12,4345,1,43,57,24,657,SD,OK
  3,1,WQ,435,676,90,3,44f,STATUS
```

Output should be as the following

```
  sed .................   file.csv
  1,14556,43634,266,242,def,45,OK
  12,4345,1,43,57,24,657,SD,STATUS
  3,1,WQ,435,676,90,3,44f,STATUS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution:

`sed "/^1,/ s/STATUS/OK/g" file.csv`